# Cross Domain ajax working in Chrome, but not in Firefox 4

Tags: firefox, iis, jquery, cross-domain

I am trying to hit a web service with a put request using jquery's ajax implementation.  Server is running iis 7.

I added these settings below in the web.config :

```
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://the-site-that-is-making-the-request.com" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
        </customHeaders>
```

My jQuery looks like this :

```
        $.ajax({
            url : 'webserviceurl',
            data : params,
            type : 'PUT',
            crossDomain : true,
            success : success,
            error : error,
        });
```

like I mentioned... got it working Chrome.. and also Safari, but not in Firefox.  Does anyone know whats up?  What am I doing wrong?  Any help with this would be most appreciated.

Comment: did you enable cross domain ajax requests in Firefox?http://dirolf.com/2007/06/enabling-cross-domain-ajax-in-firefox.html

Comment: Which Firefox version did you test with?